# IIS windows authentication error (401.1)

Tags: java, sql-server, http, iis

I have configure IIS 8.0 with PHP 5.3 , along with SQL Server.

I am not sure what is going wrong. I am able to see my JSON string in web browser , when I type in URL in the browser,

But When I passed it to the code below, it is return me

```
IIS 8.0 Detailed Error - 401.2 - Unauthorized
```

401.2 Error page in my eclipse.

I am connecting to the database via Windows Authentication. Therefore , I have set Windows Authentication enabled in my IIS. I cannot able any other authentication other than Windows authentication , then my JSONstring is not return at all from the browser as well., in that case.

I have tried the solution mentioned in the below URL

```
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942043
```

The problem still persists

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;

public class JSONTester {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        InputStream is = null;
        String json = "";

        try 
        {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/hive/get_all_products.php");
            httpPost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Any help would be great .

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer is the only browser that does the NTLM authentication using integrated mode out-of-the-box, this is why your URL works in your 'browser'. Your Java HttpClient must authenticate explicitly and answer the NTLM challenge from the server. See [HttpClient NTLM Authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html#NTLM):

> NTLM is the most complex of the authentication protocols supported by
>   HttpClient. It is a proprietary protocol designed by Microsoft with no
>   publicly available specification... NTLM
>   authentication **requires an instance of NTCredentials be available** for
>   the domain name of the server or the default credentials. Note that
>   since NTLM does not use the notion of realms HttpClient uses the
>   domain name of the server as the name of the realm. Also note that the
>   username provided to the NTCredentials should not be prefixed with the
>   domain - ie: "adrian" is correct whereas "DOMAIN\adrian" is not
>   correct...
>   HttpClient provides limited support for what is known as NTLMv1, the early version of the NTLM protocol. **HttpClient does not support NTLMv2 at all**.

The important thing to take home is that HttpClient does **not** support integrated authentication. You must provide explicit credentials, which makes it always probe to bad practices because of the requirement to provide the account password explicitly. Make sure you do not store it but ask it from the user, much the same way Firefox does when visiting a site that requests an NTLM challenge.

Read [The NTLM Authentication Protocol and Security Support Provider](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the account you are authenticating with has rights to the files in the website directory.